# inserting in .txt file does not reflect changes

Tags: c, file

I was trying to modify few records in a file.But, the changes are not reflected.
I am search the records on the bases of `roll number` of a student.

Here is the piece of code:

```
rewind(p);

printf("\nenter the roll no after which u wana enter rec\n");
scanf("%d",&val);
printf("    The record is\nrollno  name  tmks\n_________________\n");

while((fscanf(p,"%d%d%s%d",&i,&rno,name,&tmks))==4)
{
if(rno==val)
{
printf("%d  |   %s |  %d \n",rno,name,tmks);
printf("\nenter  rollNO   totalMKS and name\n");
scanf("%d",&rno);
scanf("%d",&tmks);
scanf("%s",&name);
fprintf(p,"%d      %d     %s    %d\n",i+1,rno,name,tmks);
break;
}
}
```

I am successfully been able to add records.But new insertion does not reflect changes in above code.

Where is the problem?
Sorry for old compiler, turbo c (its a compulsion).
Here is **SSCCE** :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<process.h>
void main()
{
FILE *p;int rno,tmks,i=1,val,ofset=0;char name[20],ch;
clrscr();
p=fopen("sturecord.txt","a+");

if(p!=NULL)
{
while(1)
{
printf("do u wish to enter the record? (y/n)");
ch=getch();


if(ch=='n')
{
break;
}

else
{
printf("\nenter  rollNO   totalMKS and name\n");
scanf("%d",&rno);
scanf("%d",&tmks);
scanf("%s",&name);
fprintf(p,"%d      %d     %s    %d\n",i,rno,name,tmks);
i++;
}
}
}


rewind(p);

printf("\nenter the roll no after which u wana enter rec\n");
scanf("%d",&val);
printf("    The record is\nrollno  name  tmks\n_________________\n");

while((fscanf(p,"%d%d%s%d",&i,&rno,name,&tmks))==4)
{
if(rno==val)
{
printf("%d  |   %s |  %d \n",rno,name,tmks);
printf("\nenter  rollNO   totalMKS and name\n");
scanf("%d",&rno);
scanf("%d",&tmks);
scanf("%s",&name);
fprintf(p,"%d      %d     %s    %d\n",i+1,rno,name,tmks);
break;
}
}


fclose(p);
getch();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your call to `fopen`:

```
p = fopen ("sturecord.txt", "a+");
```

If you open a file in append mode, *all* writes go the end of the file, no matter what you do. From `ISO C11 7.20.5.3 The fopen function /6`:

> Opening a file with append mode ('a' as the first character in the mode argument) causes all subsequent writes to the file to be forced to the then current end-of-file, regardless of intervening calls to the fseek function.

Typically, in order to change arbitrary parts of a file, you open it in `r+` mode since this allows you to read and write anywhere in the file, assuming you follow the rules about flushing/seeking between reads and writes in `/7` of the above mentioned ISO standard section.

But keep in mind this opening with `r+` mode will fail if the file doesn't already exist. You can usually catch that and then try to open it with `w+` but you should stay aware of the possibility of a race condition if others may be trying to create that file as well. In the case where you're the only program expected to create that file, it's generally a viable option.

Also keep in mind that there is no standard mechanism to actually *insert* data into a file. All writes will overwrite whatever data is already at that position.

If you want to actually insert data, you have a couple of options.

One is to actually shuffle the exiting data upwards in the file before writing to the now-useless area. This is not that efficient as it generally involves many read and write operations, usually at a record level.

Another is to read the current file and write it to a new file (both sequentially) and "inserting" the new data when you get to the correct point. Then you remove the old file and rename the new file. Again, this can be less than optimal although it's often more so than the previous paragraph since you tend to operate with larger chunks during reading and writing.

A third way can be *far* more efficient. It involves treating your file as a data structure (eg, a linked list) so that you can *append* information to the physical file while treating it as if it were *inserted* (in to the logical file). This removes the need for shuffling data around but at the expense of slightly more work when reading in or processing the file.

---

Expanding on the data structure method, let's assume you're creating a program that needs to store records (the payload) but you need to be able to insert and delete these records at will. We'll start by creating a structure for each record (in pseudo-code):

```
union tRecord:
    structure firstRec:
        uint32 firstRecNum
        uint32 lastRecNum
        uint32 firstFreeRecNum
        # Unused space for uint8[116]
    structure otherRec:
        uint32 prevRecNum
        uint32 nextRecNum
        uint8 payload[120]
```

We make this a union since we will basically treat the first part of the file as meta-data, containing details on the first and last logical records and the first free record.

Beyond that first part of the file, every non-free record contains both the record number of the previous and next records, and the payload itself. Since there is no record number 0 (it's preserved for the meta data), we can use that record number to indicate end of list. Translating a record number to a physical file location is simply multiplying it by the union size (128 in this case).

Hence an "empty" file consists of the following (with `???` signifying irrelevant data):

```
Byte offset  Length  Description
-----------  ------  -----------
Meta-record
          0       4  First record in file = 0
          4       4  Last record in file = 0
          8       4  First free record = 0
         12     116  ???

End of file
        128
```

With this scheme, you *process* the logical file sequentially by starting at the first record, found in `firstRec.firstRecNum` and follow the chain formed by each record's `otherRec.nextRecNum` field, acting on `otherRec.payload` as you go (stopping when the chain ends up giving you record number 0, of course).

When it comes time to *insert* a record, you simply perform the same operations you would for a doubly linked list in memory. First you need a new record, either by pulling it from the current free list, or adding it physically to the end of the file.

Then you simply adjust the pointer entries within the file to effectively insert that record into the logical order, regardless of its physical position. There is no shuffling of physical data involved, simply overwriting data that's already there.

Similarly, *deleting* a logical record doesn't involve removing it from the physical file. You simply adjust the pointers so that it's bypassed in the non-free chain, and return it to the free list. Note that the free list need only be a *singly* linked list since it can be used as a stack, always pushing and popping items at the front (the order of free records is irrelevant).

And, of course, there is no change in the code you have for *editing* an already existing record - simply overwrite the payload section and leave the pointers alone.

So the file contents that would arise from adding four records in order then deleting the middle ones would be:

```
Byte offset  Length  Description
-----------  ------  -----------
Meta-record
          0       4  First record in file = 1
          4       4  Last record in file = 4
          8       4  First free record = 2
         12     116  ???

Physical record number 1 (first logical record)
        128       4  Previous record number = 0
        132       4  Next record number = 4
        136     120  Payload 1

Physical record number 2 (first free record)
        256       4  Previous record number = ???
        260       4  Next record number = 3
        264     120  ???

Physical record number 3 (second and last free record)
        384       4  Previous record number = ???
        388       4  Next record number = 0
        392     120  ???

Physical record number 4 (second and last logical record)
        512       4  Previous record number = 1
        516       4  Next record number = 0
        520     120  Payload 4

End of file
        640
```

Comment: I have called rewind(), does that matter too?

Comment: Even if I close and open the file again, this continues

Comment: Please look at the code, even if I changed my mode, this continues.I think my 2nd insertion is overwriting the previous data.

Comment: Thanks for the data structure tip :)